# poster latex problem

Tags: posters

I am preparing a poster for my first conference. I am using a template from internet. I need to modify it and adapt the `\headerbox` for my work but i got a bad result.
I use th example in [graphtrack](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/) and I changed just the logos and the list of mails.

When I run the poster.tex, I get the second logo in the bad place and also the mail of author did not appear. How Can I resize the \headerbox to get right result
[image]

file.tex

```
\documentclass[landscape,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{palatino}

\newcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}

\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\SET}[1]  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand{\MAT}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VEC}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Video}{\SET{V}}
\newcommand{\video}{\VEC{f}}
\newcommand{\track}{x}
\newcommand{\Track}{\SET T}
\newcommand{\LMs}{\SET L}
\newcommand{\lm}{l}
\newcommand{\PosE}{\SET P}
\newcommand{\posE}{\VEC p}
\newcommand{\negE}{\VEC n}
\newcommand{\NegE}{\SET N}
\newcommand{\Occluded}{\SET O}
\newcommand{\occluded}{o}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Some math symbols used in the text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Multicol Settings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Save space in lists. Use this after the opening of the list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Begin of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Here starts the poster
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Format it to your taste with the options
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Define some colors

%\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.83,0.24,0,0.12}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}

% Draw a video
\newlength{\FSZ}
\newcommand{\drawvideo}[3]{% [0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1 1.25 1.5]
   \noindent\pgfmathsetlength{\FSZ}{\linewidth/#2}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,x=\FSZ,y=\FSZ]
   \draw[color=lightblue!50!black] (0,0) node[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,text width=\linewidth,minimum height=0] (video) {\noindent#3};
   \path [fill=lightblue!50!black,line width=0pt] 
     (video.north west) rectangle ([yshift=\FSZ] video.north east) 
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#2} {
      {[rounded corners=0.6] ($(video.north west)+(-0.7,0.8)+(\x,0)$) rectangle +(0.4,-0.6)}
    }
;
   \path [fill=lightblue!50!black,line width=0pt] 
     ([yshift=-1\FSZ] video.south west) rectangle (video.south east) 
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#2} {
      {[rounded corners=0.6] ($(video.south west)+(-0.7,-0.2)+(\x,0)$) rectangle +(0.4,-0.6)}
    }
;
   \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {
     \draw[color=lightblue!50!black] ([xshift=\x\linewidth/#1] video.north west) -- ([xshift=\x\linewidth/#1] video.south west);
   }
   \foreach \x in {0,#1} {
     \draw[color=lightblue!50!black] ([xshift=\x\linewidth/#1,yshift=1\FSZ] video.north west) -- ([xshift=\x\linewidth/#1,yshift=-1\FSZ] video.south west);
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\hyphenation{resolution occlusions}
%%
\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=lightblue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=lightblue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=lightblue,
  % Format of textbox
  textborder=roundedleft,
  % Format of text header
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.1\textheight,
%  textfont=\sc, An example of changing the text font
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
%  background=shade-tb,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
 {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{images/logolab.jpg}} 
  % Title
  {\bf\textsc{3D reconstruction by fusioning shadow \\ \vspace{.3cm}and silhouette information}\vspace{0.5em}}
  % Authors
  {\text{\{author1 and author2 \}}}
  {\text{\{author1@example.com\}}}
   % University logo
  {% The makebox allows the title to flow into the logo, this is a hack because of the L shaped logo.
    \includegraphics[scale=.35]{images/logo2.jpg}
  }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Now define the boxes that make up the poster
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Each box has a name and can be placed absolutely or relatively.
%%% The only inconvenience is that you can only specify a relative position 
%%% towards an already declared box. So if you have a box attached to the 
%%% bottom, one to the top and a third one which should be in between, you 
%%% have to specify the top and bottom boxes before you specify the middle 
%%% box.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
    % A coloured circle useful as a bullet with an adjustably strong filling
    \newcommand{\colouredcircle}{%
      \tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em); \draw[draw=black,fill=lightblue,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}

  \headerbox{Problem}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{}

  \headerbox{Contributions}{name=contribution,column=1,row=0,bottomaligned=problem}{}
\headerbox{Results}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{}

\headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0,above=bottom}{ }
  \headerbox{A Future Direction} { name=questions,column=1,span=2,aligned=references,above=bottom}{
%  \begin{multicols}{2}
%    
%  \end{multicols}
%   \vspace{0.3em}
  }

  \headerbox{Source Code}{name=references,column=3,aligned=references,above=bottom}{ }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\headerbox{Speed}{name=speed,column=2,span=2,row=0,below=results,above=references}{}
  \headerbox{Method}{name=method,column=0,below=problem,bottomaligned=speed}{}
  \headerbox{Background Model}{name=background model,column=1,below=problem,bottomaligned=speed}{ }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand where you're running into problems. Could you include the exact content of your `.tex` file that you compile to get the above result? Also, your reference to "bad result", "second logo", and "bad place" aren't very descriptive in terms of what you would like the result to look like. Could you elaborate on specifically what has gone wrong and what you would like to happen?

Comment: Could you please add your source code in the post? It would help solvers a lot to start experimenting with your code.

Comment: @Malipivo, the code source is very large. So I could not include it. In fact, I tried to include it but, it was very large and I could not post ,my question. Is there any way to include my .tex

Comment: The usual approach is to make a backup copy of your TeX (and other) files and cut the code down significantly to bare minimum, if possible. The code itself can be included in the post with four spaces in front of the lines which is best for readers as the code is formatted.

Comment: @Malipivo, Ok I included my code

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, I have already included my .tex file. My problem is logo appeans in bottom of page instead of the top (see images). In addition, the list of author mails did not appears.

Comment: @phdstudent: Please make your code _minimal_.

Comment: Without a truly minimal example and some clearer idea of the 'correct' outcome this is not going to get answered.